# Open an external link within an Ionic 3 app

Tags: ionic3

I have to open an external link in my Ionic 3 App.
The graphics of the app that is the header, the footer and the tabs must remain.
How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to these URL helpfull.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

**ionic 3**

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/in-app-browser/